# Replace values of a dictionary containing a list with other items for the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary below

```
data = {'missing_entities': [], 'score': 0.946, 'entities_found': [('location', 'blr'), ('relative_time', 'last 10 hours')]}
```

I want to replace the value `location` for the key `entities_found` with `loc` and 
the value `relative_time` with `period`.But I am unable to do that.This is what I did below

```
list(data['entities_found'][0])[0] = 'loc'
list(data['entities_found'][1])[0] = 'period'
```

I still get the original dictionary values.What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure why you are doing this,tuples are immutable,but you can override the list contents

```
data['entities_found'][0]=('loc',data['entities_found'][0][1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `entities_found` is a list of tuples. Tuples are immutable in nature. Replace the entire tuple like this:

```
data['entities_found'][0] = ('location', 'new_loc')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
list(data['entities_found'][0])
```

Creates a **new list**, which you then use index-based assignment on, but never keep a reference to the new list, so it is immediately reclaimed. The original object is never touched.

Even if tuples were mutable, like lists, this wouldn't work. Observe:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(x)[0] = 99
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Or perhaps more clearly:

```
>>> ts = [('a','b'), ('c','d')]
>>> list(ts[0]) # convert object at index 0 to list
['a', 'b']
>>> ts
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')] # original object hasn't changed
```

You'll have to approach this doing something like:

```
>>> ts = [('a','b'), ('c','d')]
>>> first, second = ts
>>> ts[0] = 'foo', first[1]
>>> ts[1] = 'bar', second[1]
>>> ts
[('foo', 'b'), ('bar', 'd')]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that values of entities found key are tuples, therefore you can't update single value of tuple. You have to either change tuple to list, or update tuple with another tuple.

```
data['entities_found'][0] = ('loc', data['entities_found'][0][1])
data['entities_found'][1] = ('period', data['entities_found'][1][1])
```

^ This is second way described above.

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are immutable in Python. So, if you find yourself having to edit the values inside a tuple, perhaps a list would serve your purposes better.

If you're really insistent about doing it, you need to convert the tuple to a list, make the string changes in this list, the convert the list back to a tuple and re-insert it into the dictionary.

Here is one way:

```
a = list(data['entities_found'][0])
a[0] = 'loc'

b = list(data['entities_found'][1])
b[0] = 'period'

data['entities_found'][0] = tuple(a)
data['entities_found'][1] = tuple(b)
```

Output:

```
{'entities_found': [('loc', 'blr'), ('period', 'last 10 hours')],
 'missing_entities': [],
 'score': 0.946}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuple in python is immutable. So can't really assign a value.
Learn more about this here: http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/10/python-tuples-immutable-but-potentially-changing.html